# How to handle standard status with Spring WebClient?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to handle standard http errors the same way. How can I do it with Spring `WebClient`? Instead of hanging status check on each call below

```
webClient.get()
    .uri("http://localhost:8081/resource")
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
        // some error handling logic
    })
    .bodyToMono(MyPojo.class);
```

Comment: If your `webClient` is a `singleton`, you can add `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor` filter to webclient on bean creation where you can write common error handling logic for all webservice calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution based on @akreddy.21's comment

Add `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor` filter to webclient on bean creation where you can write common error handling logic for all webservice calls.